# How does a mutex lock work with a singleton?

Tags: go, locking, mutex

I implemented singleton with db connector.
It works fine but i cant understand what LOCK (**mutex.Lock()**) is doing.

I tried to understand that but maybe someone here could tell me something more about this.

I understand it like this way ->
*After I use Lock() my whole code between Lock and Unlock can by run by just ONE goroutine.*
if this is truth isn't that a bottleneck? Isn't that slowing my app so much? every gorutine must wait for another end execute this code.

```
package singleton

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var connector *sql.DB
var mutex = &sync.Mutex{}

func OpenConnection() *sql.DB {
    if connector == nil {
        mutex.Lock()
        defer mutex.Unlock()
        if connector == nil {
            fmt.Println("Creating Single Instance Now")
            var err error
            connector, err = sql.Open("mysql", "db_user:.db_password@/books")

            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }

    return connector
}
```

```
package server

import (
    "connection/singleton"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "strings"
)

var connector *sql.DB

func SelectQuery(query string) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    connector = singelton.OpenConnection()
    query = strings.ToLower(query)
    if !strings.Contains(query, "select") {
        panic("Can't use select query to run different query")
    }

    results, err := connector.Query(query)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

    return results, err
}
```

Comment: 1. Your implementation is broken; double locking  doesn't work. Your code is racy. 2. Mutexes are a common thing, just read it up how they work. 3. Opening a connection to the database is done once, not for  each request. 4. Yes, this would be an awful bottleneck, but you should not do it like this anyway.

Comment: hmm where do you see double locking? i have only one mu.Lock()
i used this article to make this code: https://progolang.com/how-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-go/

Comment: Sorry, "double locking" was not the best term (double-checking singleton is better): Checking  for == nil and then locking and then rececking for == nil is **totally** **wrong** as it is racy and racy code in Go is _always_ _wrong_ . Even the article you took this code from states this: "it is still technically the wrong way to do it." (What the article gets wrong is that it is not 99.99% of the time correct, it is wrong 100% as no racy code ever is correct).If  you want  a singleton use sync.Once (as the article explains).

Comment: What do you mean saying "racy code"

i modified the code follow your advice and i got this:
https://pastebin.com/Gg54tHRc
it's working fine and i go just one db connector object.

Comment: Racy means two things read and/or write the same memory concurrently without proper  synchronisation (Googleing helps). Get used to run your code under the race detector (i.e. with the -race flag). If the race detector finds a race your  code is wrong (even if it happens to do what you want it to do.)

Comment: "isn't that a bottleneck?" yes, that is the explicit purpose of a mutex, to create a bottleneck to avoid concurrency issues. You're correct that it can also cause performance issues, but when the tradeoff is between performance and correctness, correctness will always be more important; to improve performance, you'd have to seek ways to reduce locking without sacrificing correctness.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand it like this way -> After I use Lock() my whole code between Lock and Unlock can by run by just ONE goroutine. if this is truth isn't that a bottleneck? Isn't that slowing my app so much? every gorutine must wait for another end execute this code.

The reason why we use mutex here is to initialize the DB connection only once. This will happen only in the beginning. Once you get the connection, the OpenConnection will always return the connection without entering the mutex block.
So there won't be any performance issues.

You can also achieve the same using `sync.Once` method without using mutex and double checking.